# Sort thinking sphinx by attribute AND @random?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, sphinx

So I'd like to be able to sort first by an attribute, and then amongst those with the same attribute value, sort randomly.

As in:

```
{ :sort_mode => :extended, :order => "attribute DESC, @random ASC" }
```

In my case the attribute is boolean, so I just want the ones that are `true` to all display before the ones that are `false`, but for the order within each of the `true` and `false` buckets to be random.

For some reason, this does not return any results. If I modify the above, and change @random to @relevance, it works:

```
{ :sort_mode => :extended, :order => "attribute DESC, @relevance ASC" }
```

Is there something wrong with using @random to sort along with other attributes? If so, is there a different solution to my problem??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use @random (your first example), can you look at raw search results - there may be an error or warning that could explain more:

```
search = ThinkingSphinx.search(
  :sort_mode => :extended,
  :order     => 'attribute DESC, @random ASC'
)
search.results
search.results[:error]
```

Comment: that shows: index service_core,service_delta: sort-by attribute '@random' not found

Comment: What version of Sphinx are you using?

Comment: 0.9.9. actually i read somewhere that it's a limitation of sphinx: can't sort by @random and another attribute. but it was also a post in 2008, and it said they were working on fixing the issue? maybe it works on 1.10-beta? but from my understanding thinking sphinx's support for the beta isn't too good?